# How to check db value is valid or not valid in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to check a value in database and if is available set `ViewBag` to `true` and if it is not available set `ViewBag` to `false` but I can't cast database values to bool for checking.

This my code :

```
using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var userinfo = (db.userinfoes.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userid == username));

    if(userinfo.userid == username)
    {
        ViewBag.isvalid = "true";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.isvalid = "false";
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code nullreferenceexception can occure if no user with username does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Any` like this:

```
using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var isExists = db.userinfoes.Any(u => u.userid == username);

    ViewBag.isvalid = isExists ? "true" : "false";
}
```